# Creating a record with macro

Tags: macros, clojure, record

I have a record `(defrecord Rec [id])`

I work with it like

```
(def my ( Rec. 2 ))
(println (:id my))
```

Now I want to replace record def with macro. So that I could write just

```
(r 2) 
(println (:id my))
```

I wrote macro

```
(defmacro r [id]
   (list 'def 'my (symbol "(") 'Rec. id (symbol ")")))
```

I checked it with macroexpand

```
(macroexpand-1 '(r 2))  => (def my ( Rec. 2 ))
```

But I get `RuntimeException: Too many arguments to def` on `(r 2)`.

Comment: "Now I want to replace record def with macro." Why?

Comment: @Alex Taggart, Because I want to create a DSL like stuff. Also example in question is simplified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating a symbol out of a left paren is not the same as eval-ing text with a left paren. No special significance is attached to the former; the latter causes the reader to produce a nested list which is then evaluated.

In other words, Clojure evaluates data structures, not text (or a list of symbols). When you type something in the REPL, that text is read into a data structure, then the data structure is evaluated.

For this to work correctly, the macro needs to produce a nested list itself:

```
(defmacro r [id]
  (list 'def 'my (list 'Rec. id)))
```

Or better yet, use the syntax quote operator:

```
(defmacro r [id]
  `(def my (Rec. ~id)))
```

For illustrative purposes, you can see what happens when Clojure code is read as text:

```
(read-string "(def my (Rec. 2))")
=> (def my (Rec. 2))
(map type (read-string "(def my (Rec. 2))"))
=> (clojure.lang.Symbol clojure.lang.Symbol clojure.lang.PersistentList)
```